# Deserialize to get an object instance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to deserialize django rest framework serialized data to get back an object, i.e to do something like Modelname.objects.get(**serialized_data). However when I try the following, I get validation error because drf is attempting to create a new instance and it already exists. I only need to retrieve existing object. How can I do that without resorting to manually getting each field parameter from the dict?

My code:

```
class ClinicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Clinic
        fields = [
            'clinicid',
            'name',
            'label',
            'email',
            'mobile',
            'alternate',
            'address',
            'locationlink',
            'googlepaynumber',
            'upi_id',
            'reviewlink',
            'locationlink',
            'bookinglink'
        ]

clinic = biovardata['linkedclinic']
print("\n Deserializing clinic..")
print("Clinic:", clinic)
clinicserializer = ClinicSerializer(data=clinic, many=False)
if clinicserializer.is_valid():
    print("Clinic Serializer is valid")
    cl = Clinic(clinicserializer.validated_data)

    print("Clinic is ", clinic)
else:
    print("Clinic Serializer is not valid")
    print(clinicserializer.errors)
```

My output:

```
Deserializing clinic..
Clinic: {'clinicid': 21, 'name': "Clinic name", 'label': 'joelper'}
Clinic Serializer is not valid
{'name': [ErrorDetail(string='clinic with this name already exists.', code='unique')], 'label': [ErrorDetail(string='clinic with this label already exists.', code='unique')]}
```

Comment: If the name is a unique value, why don't you get the Clinic by doing `Clinic.objects.get(name=clinic['name'])`

Comment: @Vincent I was thinking DRF has a smarter way of doing this rather than first retrieve each dict key value and then doing a get.

Comment: Can you add the serializer? if that is a ModelSerializer  this is expected , because it validates for CRUD operations. For your purpose I think you can use normal Serializer.

Comment: @UzzalH.Mohammad For this question I had simplified my code. What is the correct way to deserialize? Do we need to get the key value, and go a `.objects.get`? Seems rather counter-intuitive to the ease that DRF offers

Comment: What you did before i mean .objects.get(**serialized_data) should have worked. Can you add 'id' in the serializer fields list and try again?

Comment: DRF provides RetriveAPIView for retrieving an object. You may look into that and avoid those struggle.